# Java 8 streams forEach

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to iterate over an ArrayList of objects and print out the 'name' attribute of each object in the list. However, I cannot access the object's attributes even though I have getter method for the name in the Person class. Here is some code:

```
 ArrayList persons = new ArrayList<>();
 persons.add(new Person("Name","Age"));
 persons.add(new Person("Name1","Age1"));
 persons.add(new Person("Name2","Age2"));

persons
 .stream()
 .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));   //giving an error

  forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));  //no error
```

It wont allow me to do this. all I can have just 'e' in the print command, which prints the reference numbers of the objects.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: What is the exception you're getting?

Comment: Turn on all Java compiler warnings.  The compiler will warn you that `ArrayList persons` with no generic type is a "raw type" and should be something like `ArrayList<Person> persons` instead.

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/4856258)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see what the compiler says.  (This would have been easier if you had provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

```
$ javac Main.java
Main.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
                                              ^
  symbol:   method getName()
  location: variable e of type Object
Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

You get a warning and an error.  The error says that `e` is of type `Object` that – as we know – has no method `getName`. This should alert you because, after all, you've put objects of type `Person` in your `List`, no? The warning says that we should re-compile with the `-Xlint:unchecked` flag for details.  So let's do it.

```
$ javac -Xlint:unchecked Main.java
Main.java:28: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
        persons.add(new Person("Name1", 1));
                   ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
Main.java:29: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
        persons.add(new Person("Name2", 2));
                   ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
Main.java:30: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
        persons.add(new Person("Name3", 3));
                   ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
Main.java:33: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to forEach(Consumergt;) as a member of the raw type Stream
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
                    ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
Main.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
                                              ^
  symbol:   method getName()
  location: variable e of type Object
1 error
4 warnings
```

Apparently, the compiler is complaining about `persons` being “raw”. [Reading up on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) tells us that we should specify the type of object we want to put into the list.  So set's do it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

final class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(final String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}


public final class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();  // <--- here ---
        persons.add(new Person("Name1", 1));
        persons.add(new Person("Name2", 2));
        persons.add(new Person("Name3", 3));
        persons
            .stream()
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getName()));
    }
}
```

And now it works!

```
$ javac Main.java && java -cp . Main
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

Comment: Yes it works now! All I did was declare the generic type for arraylist. ArrayList<Persons> = new ArrayList<>(); Thank you so much! I have been hitting my head on the wall over this

Comment: @Nero you should use `List<Person>` rather than `ArrayList<Person>` (code to the interface, not the implementation). Also, it isn't necessary to use the `-Xlint:unchecked` compiler switch. A plain `-Xlint` will turn on *all* diagnostics, and is easier to type.